# Is my company legally required to remove an email from our mailing list that isn't on our mailing list?

Tags: email-marketing

Today a customer tried to unsubscribe from our mailing list. The email (anonymized) she entered into the unsubscribe box was `x@domain.com`. `x@domain.com` was not in our database, so the unsubscribe failed. I had a look at our database to double check, and I found that while `x@domain.com` is indeed not in the database, `x@domain.com.au` is. After more research, I found out that `domain.com` and `domain.com.au` are owned by the same company and emails addressed to either domain reach the same inbox.

So from the customer's perspective, `x@domain.com` is equivalent to `x@domain.com.au`, but from my company's database's perspective, the two emails are not equivalent. Are we breaking the law by not unsubscribing her? My gut is that it's unreasonable to expect us to know that `domain.com` and `domain.com.au` are equivalent.

I manually unsubscribed her because I understand what her intention is, but should our system handle this automatically?

Comment: What is your jurisdiction (country/state)? Are you aware of any law that actually requires you to unsubscribe people on their request?

From a non-legal perspective, many mailing lists avoid this problem by explicitly saying 'You are subscribed as xxx@yyy.com in the body of each email', and have an unsubscribe link which encodes that email, so the user doesn't need to enter it.